# Coredata multithreading violation in perform block

Tags: objective-c, swift, multithreading, core-data, magicalrecord

For the life of me I can't figure out what's wrong. I'm trying to figure out why coredata is saying I have a concurrency issue. In my tableviewCellForRow method im trying to load more data when the user scrolls down completely. I want to do this on a background context, then save the results. The background context is a child of my main context (it has concurrency type private). I'm doing:

```
            let backgroundContext = NSManagedObjectContext.mr_newPrivateQueue()
            backgroundContext.parent = NSManagedObjectContext.mr_default()
            backgroundContext.perform({ 
                self.loadMoreConversationsThenSave(inContext: backgroundContext)

                // We want to run any UI updates on the main thread or we have weird crashes/undefined results
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            })
```

Then in the loadMoreConversations method looks like this:

```
fileprivate func loadMoreConversationsThenSave(inContext context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
    let oldestConvoIndex = (conversationsFRC.fetchedObjects?.count ?? 0 ) - 1

    if oldestConvoIndex > 0 {
        let oldestConvo = conversationsFRC.fetchedObjects?[oldestConvoIndex] as? Conversation
        let oldestConvoInContext = context.object(with: (oldestConvo?.objectID)!) as? Conversation
        let oldestCallId = oldestConvoInContext?.most_recent_call_id
        let oldestCall = FetchRequestHelper.fetch(class: Call.self, withID: oldestCallId, inContext: context) as? Call
        if let date = oldestCall?.created_at {
            BPDKAPIClient.shared().getConversationsSince(date, isAfterDate: false, completion: { (objects, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print("ERROR - failed to fetch conversations since date \(error)")
                } else {
                    if objects?.count == 0 {
                        self.recevedAllCallsFromServer = true
                    } else {

                        // Since we're in the callback this is going to be run on the main thread, so we need to wrap
                        // it in a perform block
                        context.perform({
                            Conversation.parseConversationAndCalls(objects, in: context) //points here
                            do {
                                try context.save()
                            } catch {
                                print("ConversationsTVC: Error saving: \(error)")
                            }
                            // We want to run any UI updates on the main thread or we have weird crashes/undefined results
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                self.tableView.reloadData()
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

The fetch request helper class creates a fetch request and a FRC and just grabs the object with that ID and returns it. It's all done with the same context that's passed in. Notice here that when the API call `getConversationsSince` finishes, we want to do another `perform` on the same context because the completion of that function is launched on the main thread instead of the same background thread.

The breakpoint points to the line with the comment beside it: `Conversation.parseConversationAndCalls(objects, in: context)`

And this is what that method looks like:

```
+ (void) parseConversationAndCalls:(NSArray*)objects inContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*)localContext {

    for (NSArray *conversationBundle in objects) {

        NSArray *conversationsCallData = conversationBundle[1];
        NSArray *conversationData = conversationBundle[0];
        NSNumber *convoID = [BPDObject scrubbedInteger:conversationData[0]];
        Conversation *convo = (Conversation*) [FetchRequestHelper fetchWithClass:Conversation.self withID:convoID inContext:localContext]; //points here

        if (convo == nil) {
            convo = [Conversation insertInManagedObjectContext:localContext];
        }

        [convo updateWithValues:conversationData];
        Contact *contact = (Contact*) [FetchRequestHelper fetchWithClass:Contact.self withID:convo.contact_id inContext:localContext];

        // getCOnversations since date will supply all call data as well
        for (NSArray *callData in conversationsCallData) {

            NSNumber *callID = [BPDObject scrubbedInteger:callData[1]];
            Call *call = (Call*) [FetchRequestHelper fetchWithClass:Call.self withID:callID inContext:localContext];

            if (call.objectID.isTemporaryID) {
                call = [Call insertInManagedObjectContext:localContext];
            }

            [call updateWithValues:callData inContext:localContext];
            call.contact = contact;
        }
    }
}
```

the line pointed to in this method is: `Conversation *convo = (Conversation*) [FetchRequestHelper fetchWithClass:Conversation.self withID:convoID inContext:localContext];` or any of the other FetchRequestHelper methods. I don't think it has to do with the fetch request helper either (i've looked over it 50 times) but here it is if you're curious:

```
class FetchRequestHelper: NSObject {

    public class func fetchRequest(theClass: BPDObject.Type, predicate: NSPredicate, sortDescriptors: NSArray, inContext context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> {
        let request = theClass.mr_requestAllSorted(by: "", ascending: true, with: predicate, in: context)
        request.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors as? [NSSortDescriptor]
        request.includesPropertyValues = false
        request.fetchBatchSize = 20
        request.includesPendingChanges = false

        return request
    }

    public class func fetchedResultsController(forRequest request: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>, context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult> {
        let fetchedResultController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

        return fetchedResultController
    }

    public class func fetch(class someClass: BPDObject.Type, withID id: NSNumber!, inContext context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> BPDObject? {
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", id)
        let request = FetchRequestHelper.fetchRequest(theClass: someClass, predicate: predicate, sortDescriptors: [], inContext: context)
        let frc = FetchRequestHelper.fetchedResultsController(forRequest: request, context: context)

        do {
            try frc.performFetch()
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failed to perform fetch from FetchedResultsController: \(error)")
        }

        return frc.fetchedObjects?.first as? BPDObject
    }
}
```

I suspect it might have something to do with the API calls completion block but I'm already wrapping the next operations in performBlock. What could possibly be the issue?